# Inserting blank line between strings that starts with different number

Tags: bash

Please help me with that.
I Want to transform the file

```
1.0  0.1  0.02
1.0  0.2  0.04
1.1 -0.2 0.1
1.1 -0.1 0.1
1.2  1.0   0.2
```

into

```
1.0  0.1  0.02
1.0  0.2  0.04

1.1 -0.2 0.1
1.1 -0.1 0.1

1.2  1.0   0.2
```

Comment: Which criteria for insert string between lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `awk`:

```
pax> echo '1.0  0.1  0.02
1.0  0.2  0.04
1.1 -0.2 0.1
1.1 -0.1 0.1
1.2  1.0   0.2' | awk 'last!=""&&last!=$1{print""}{print;last=$1}'
```

The output of that is:

```
1.0  0.1  0.02
1.0  0.2  0.04

1.1 -0.2 0.1
1.1 -0.1 0.1

1.2  1.0   0.2
```

Breaking it down, `last` is initially set to the empty string. The code is then:

```
last != "" && last != $1 { print "" }
                         { print; last = $1}
```

That first clause will select all input lines where the first field doesn't match the previous first field (other than the first input line). If it does match, it outputs a blank line.

The second clause selects all input lines (no condition part) and simply outputs the current input line and saves the first field of it into the `last` variable for use in the next input line.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to loop through the lines of the file.  Something like

```
while read line
do
    # some logic here
done < file_to_read.txt
```

now in place of "some logic here," you need to check if the first number is the same as the previous line.  Something like

```
if [[ "$prevnum" != "$curnum" ]]
then
    echo
fi
```

You can get the first space deliminated number using something like

```
set -- $line
curnum=$1
```

or else

```
curnum=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
```

or

```
curnum=$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f2)
```

I'll let you put it together from there.